# Filtering across pages in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, filtering

I have several pages with simple tables. I have set up relationships so all tables are "linked". When I select a given row in one table, the other tables are filtered by that selection. This works fine when all tables are on the same page. I would also like this to happen on all pages. I suspect it has to do with "Drill Through" functionality but I can't get it to work.

Can any one help or point me to some good video that explain

This works fine when all tables are on the same page. I would also like this to happen on all pages. I suspect it has to do with "Drill Through" functionality but I can't get it to work.

I can achieve a similar effect with synced slicers, but this would require lots of slicers, which I'd like to avoid, takes up too much space.

Can any one help or point me to some good video that explain

Comment: Interactions work only on the same page (as [mentioned here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/consumer/end-user-interactions)). Drills might work for you, but you have to turn pages into specific drill-target-pages, [read here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-drillthrough)

Comment: Yes that does seem to be the way to go... Drill Through does seem to do what I want, after much effort I did get it to work, but I then needed a Bookmark in order to Reset the Page back to the unfiltered state... so close and yet so far :(.. thanks for you efforts